# Special characters in Solr filter fq

Tags: filter, solr, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to filter with `fq` for fields having special characters, particularly parentheses.  For example, given the document:

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
  <doc>
    <arr name="town_snc">
      <str>Hartford (Connecticut)</str>
    </arr>
  </doc>
</result>
```

I want to do e.g. `?fq:town_snc=Hartford (Connecticut)`

I'm not getting any results; I presume that the parentheses need to be escaped, but I was not able to find the escaping method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the "field" qparser allows you to not have to do any escaping:

```
fq={!field f=town_snc}Hartford (Connecticut)
```

Or you can use the normal lucene query parser and use double quotes (but then you must still escape some things like quotes)

```
fq=town_snc:"Hartford (Connecticut)"
```

Or you could use backslash escaping too (just remember to also escape the space).

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax