# Solr 4.0 filter query (fq) with unicode characters

Tags: unicode, solr

I am trying to figure out what's the best approach to this problem where some of the terms I am filtering on (with fq) have unicode characters, terms such as:

```
CompanyName™
Something®
```

With my current index, Solr fails to return any results. Is [ASCII folding](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ASCIIFoldingFilter) at indexing time the right way or using the [field qparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265056/special-characters-in-solr-filter-fq); or may be there is something else I should do? I am on Solr 4.0.

Comment: Except this filter doesn't fold to ASCII but to some other codepage (Latin-1 I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) at index time. This has proved to provide the best results in the scenarios where we have used it.